# Finding GIT STASH from previous branch?

Tags: git, git-stash

The scenario:

- working on Branch A.
- needed to pause to work on a different branch.
- ran `git stash` and then checked out Branch B.
- worked on Branch B a bit then needed to go back to Branch A.
- ran `git stash` on Branch B and then checked out Branch A.

Here's where I screwed up

- ran `git stash apply` on Branch A thinking it was going to apply my stash from Branch A back.

It didn't. It took the stashed files from Branch B and applied it to Branch A.

Is there any way to back out of this and get the changes I originally stashed while in Branch A? Or are they gone?

Comment: `git stash` works by making a commit (well, really, two or three commits) that are on *no* branch. So there's no such thing as a stash "from" some branch—stashes are independent of branches.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-stash the changes you just applied (`git stash`) then find in the stash list (`git stash list`) the one you need, then `git stash pop <stashRefYouSpottedEarlier>` to finish the process.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. Alas, nothing got updated. It's as if the old stash was empty. Looks like I goofed up something elsewhere too. Sigh.

Comment: @DA. It might not be too late. Did you try to get it back from the reflog?

Comment: What's a reflog? What I did was switched back to branch a, ran `git stash list`, found the one that was labeled for that branch, then `git stash apply [branch hash]`. But then it said 'up to date with branch...nothing added to commit...` as if the stash was empty.

Comment: @DA. Won't be able to answer right away :-/ But I'd suggest reading [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)